# Generic ConvertTo?

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to figure out how I could do some sort of `ConvertTo` while using reflection and generics.

I have 2 concrete files with properties (could be: simple types, nullable times, DateTime)

I want to do mapping between these files. One will be the source file and one will the destination file.

I have ran into a problem though of how do I convert? Say I have a string that looks like a GUID. How could I convert this?

Yet, I need something to handle at the same times strings to int, double, decmial or whatever.

I know there are mappers out there like automapper and injecter but since my name don't match it makes it hard to use these as there is no real naming convention. I actually have 3rd file that will have all the names and what they map to.

Example

Source Class

```
 public class Source
    {
        public string test1 { get; set; }
        public int test2 { get; set; }
        public int? test3 { get; set; }
        public double test4 { get; set; }
        public double? test5 { get; set; }
        public DateTime test6 { get; set; }
        public DateTime? test7 { get; set; }
        public int test8 { get; set; }
        public string test9 { get; set; }

    }

 Source source = new Source()
            {
                test1 = "hi",
                test2 = 1,
                test3 =  null,
                test4 = 50.50,
                test5 = null,
                test6 = DateTime.Now,
                test7 = null,
                test8 = 50,
                test9 = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()                    
            };
```

Destination

```
 public class Destination
    {
        public string Test1 { get; set; }
        public int Test2 { get; set; }
        public int? Test3 { get; set; }
        public double Test4 { get; set; }
        public double? Test5 { get; set; }
        public DateTime Test6 { get; set; }
        public DateTime Test7 { get; set; }

        public double Test8 { get; set; }

        public Guid Test9 { get; set; }
    }
```

Before you say that automapper can handle lowercase vs upper case not that is just an example my casing in my actual project is alot different. I am trying to  to convert a double to an int and a string to guid.

here is my mapping file

```
{
  "test1": {
    "to": "Test1"
  },
  "test2": {
    "to": "Test2"
  },
  "test3": {
    "to": "Test3"
  },
  "test4": {
    "to": "Test4"
  },
  "test5": {
    "to": "Test5"
  },
  "test6": {
    "to": "Test6"
  },
  "test7": {
    "to": "Test7"
  },
  "test8": {
    "to": "Test8"
  },
  "test9": {
    "to": "Test9"
  }
}
```

Comment: You can make automapper read the 3rd file and set up the mapping if the file is parseable by machine code.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - Can you provide a link or example to this.

Comment: @chobo2 Looking at your example, automapper will work out of the box with no configuration at all because the names are the same except for capitalization. If it won't always match, [here is a quick example I threw together](https://gist.github.com/leftler/fdfe29e286430aec29f7).

Comment: I just used that in my testing to keep things simple but in my real data it not going to be just lower case to uppercase. In many cases the names are going to be spelt differently between the two classes(like one might abbreviate a word and another not). If I am understanding your example right you will have a files that you read in and then make that into a concentrate class then map it using that?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - where is the types coming from for Source & Destination in IMappingExpression<Source, Destination>

Comment: I think, I understand now just trying it out now.

Comment: @chobo2 they come from your first two code examples in your question.

Comment: Yea, I think I got it. I passed them in as Setup<T,TA> that why I can use any 2 concrete classes. Now I was thinking since I am using automapper if it is possible to take what you gave me and make it be able to do complex types. Like if I would add another Class to Both Source and Dest. How could I map it? I tried to add   "SourceSub.getMe": {
    "to":  "DestinationSub.GetMe"
  } but that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with that third file and build a Dictionary<String, Type> that would map names to C# types. You didn't provide examples of your files so just sample code here:

```
Dictionary<String, Type> map = new Dictionary<String, Type>();
foreach(KeyValuePair<String, String> nameToTypeName in entry_in_third_file)
{
    map.Add(nameToTypeName.Key, Type.GetType(nameToTypeName.Value));
}
```

Next actuall convertion:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> nameAndValue in entry_in_properties)
{
    Type targetType = map[nameAndValue.Key];
    String value = nameAndValue.Value;
    Object convertedValue = System.Convert.ChangeType(value, targetType);
}
```

Of course that's just basic example, without peek into those files you have it's hard to tell more. You'll need to create that types dictionary depending on the direction of conversion.

Also this is just for simple string to object conversions. If you need something more sophisticated then take a look at [TypeConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx) which allows you to create own converting classes for each type you need.

Comment: I am doing something similar where I get the "targetType" from the destination property and get it's underlying type and then use ChangeType but it was unable to convert the string to a Guid.